# Steps to dipslay aerial photos as tiles using tilemill

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, tilemill

I am new to tilemill and trying to find out steps to display aerial photos as tiles in tilemill.

The aerial photos are saved as geotiff files and I tried to create a new layer using them as the datasource.
Howerver, I have no luck that the geotiff images and the layer settings are displayed as shown below.

[image]
[image]
The questions I want as are follows:

1. Would it be possible to show aerial phots as tiles in tilemill?
2. If possible, what would be the basic flow or steps to achieve the goal?

I followed the basic guids available on the internet such as below already.
http://tilemill-project.github.io/tilemill/docs/guides/reprojecting-geotiff/